# How do I set the background color of text in a nstextview?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsattributedstring

I have a nstextview, and I was wondering how to set the background color of it. I've tried quite a few things, but none seem to work. They just set the actually text color. I have  a NSColorWell, called `colorBox`, and the textview is called `doc`, in case someone wants to know. I use `[self.colorBox color] to get the color in the NSColorWell

Comment: `[doc.textStorage setForegroundColor:yourColor];`?

Answer (score 5):

`NSTextView` has [`backgroundColor` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTextView/backgroundColor). Try setting it to something else like `NSColor.redColor()`.

It also has [`drawsBackground` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTextView/drawsBackground) which need to be set to `true` to make it work.

```
let textView1 = NSTextView()
textView1.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor()
textView1.drawsBackground = true
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color of the attributed string you must add the attribute to it:

```
[mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:selectedRange];
```

Comment: UIColor for Cocoa development?

Comment: Doesn't work. I modified the code to be : `[self.doc.textStorage addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[NSColor redColor] range:self.doc.selectedRange];` and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboards, TextViews have three sections in the Attributes Inspector, "Text View", "Scroll View", and "View". "Background color" is the fifth option in the "View" section.

Comment: I'm using cocoa, not cocoa touch (iOS).